# difference between contextual actions & surface actions in android 4.0+

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i need to clarify for my app so that can use the terminology for ease of development in my android app.

Any links or related reference information will be appreciated.

Comment: Since the term "surface action" is not used in Android development, you might consider editing your question to explain what you mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Its used in the [Developer design page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/new.html).
And that's what the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are citing is using the word "surface" as a verb, not an adjective. In this case, "surface" means "to show" or "to display".

The sentence that I suspect is the source of your confusion:

> When selecting data, contextual action bars allow you to surface actions.

...could be rewritten as:

> When selecting data, contextual action bars allow you to display actions that formerly had not been displayed.

Comment: Actually i saw this on two contexts. however i loosely posted the other link,thinking it may sound the same in both.
See this [Link](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#small-contextual). I doubt it means same in here too.

Comment: @DiabloGeto: In that second page, "surface" is also used as a verb.